# PUT works with POSTMAN but not with AXIOS

Tags: asp.net-web-api, vue.js, axios

I am trying to update a record in the database. The back end is in C# ASP.NET and the front end is in vuejs. GET, POST methods work with POSTMAN and AXIOS. PUT method do works with POSTMAN but not with axios. Below is the trimmed version of the axios.

```
axios({
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'http://localhost:64427/api/employees/update',
  header:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data: {
       QUAD: n_emp.QUAD,
       EMAIL: n_emp.EMAIL,
       ACTIF_O_N:n_emp.ACTIF_O_N
  }
}).then(response => {
   this.$router.push('/management/employee/overview')
}
```

Below is the controller

```
 [HttpPut]
 [ActionName("update")]
 public HttpResponseMessage UpdateEmployee([FromBody]EmployeeFormVM employee)
 {
    var db = new KronosDB("public");
    var response = Request.CreateResponse();
    EMPLOYEE updateemployee = db.Employees.Where(e => e.QUAD == employee.QUAD).FirstOrDefault();
    updateemployee.QUAD = employee.QUAD;
    updateemployee.ACTIF_O_N = employee.ACTIF_O_N;
    updateemployee.EMAIL = employee.EMAIL;
 }
```

I have this at the top of the controller.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:8080", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

I get the message below

> Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight
>   response.

Comment: That should work [according to my reading of the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors). Possibly your idea of "at the top of the controller" and mine are a little different.

Comment: @Quentin I put it above the `public class EmployeesController : ApiController`

Answer (score 1):

Following the instructions from documentation

[Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

I added these lines below in **WebApiConfig.cs** in the *Register* function to solve this issue.

```
config.EnableCors();
```